# Run-time error '3061'. Too few parameters. Expected 3. (Access 2007 and 2010)

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, recordset

I have query like below and I can't add more conditions.

```
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Value1],[Value2] FROM Query1 where DATA_1 >= #" & Me.Tekst22.Value & "# and DATA_2 <= #" & Me.Tekst24.Value & "#", dbOpenSnapshot)
```

It works great but I need to add two more conditiones :

```
and ([Value3] = Me.Tekst34 or [Value4] = Me.Tekst34)
```

If I add code like this

```
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Value1],[Value2] FROM Query1 where DATA_1 >= #" & Me.Tekst22.Value & "# and DATA_2 <= #" & Me.Tekst24.Value & "# and ([Value3] = " & Me.Tekst34.Value & " or [Value4] = " & Me.Tekst34.Value & " ", dbOpenSnapshot)
```

I've got:
Run-time error '3061'. Too few parameters. Expected 3

Please help me to correct this error.

additional:
Next step after run this Query1 is print values to text file.

```
    Open "c:\test.txt" For Output As #1
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Query1")
    Do While Not rst.EOF

    Print #1, rst!VALUE1 & " " & rst!VALUE2
    rst.MoveNext
    Loop
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Close #1
```

That is what I need. Run Query1 (now it's with all needed parametrs) and print two values to text file.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing bracket in the SQL, it should finish `Me.Tekst34.Value & ")"`

If your Tekst34 is a string, you need to enclose it in quotes in the SQL :

`"# and ([Value3] = """ & Me.Tekst34.Value & """ or [Value4] = """ & Me.Tekst34.Value & """)"`

(to include `"` in a string constant one must put `""`).

Comment: I did it but now I've got: Run-time error '3061'. Too few parameters. Expected 2

Comment: Answer edited for the case where Tekst34 is a string.

Comment: Now I've got: Run-time error '3061'. Too few parameters. Expected 4 - Please read my comment for PaulFrancis.

Comment: Maybe you should construct your query/queries in the Query Editor. Add one paramter, test, then the next. When it's all good, switch to SQL view to copy to your code.

Comment: @maxhugen I have rebuilt Query1 and it works fine, reads data from Tekstboxes on FORM and shows property values. But If I change code to
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Query1") I've got: Run-time error '3061'. Too few parameters. Expected 3. Maybe is other way to use Print #1, rst!VALUE1 & " " & rst!VALUE2 from this query ?

Comment: Ah, think I see the issue. You cannot use references to objects such as your form textbox, that you want to open in a vba recordset. Don't know why Access doesn't allow that, but it doesn't! Instead, construct your query without the criteria that references the text boxes. Then, add a string variable to your code, eg strSQL, and construct the sql criteria in the code. eg "SELECT Query1.* FROM Query1 WHERE Value1='" & Me.Tekst1 & "' AND Value2='" & Me.Tekst1 & "'" ... (and so on).

Comment: The advantage of using the variable strSQL is that you can debug it: stop the code when it has assembled the sql string, and see what it contains using the Immediate window (?strSQL). You can then copy that string, and paste it into a new query in SQL view, to test that it works OK, or to find a potential problem etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is what your Code should be, you need to make sure the number of opening parenthesis is equal to the closing ones. I have taken that the Value3 and Value4 are Text type in the table. More importantly; make sure they actually exist in the table.

```
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Value1],[Value2] FROM Query1 " & _
                                  "WHERE ((DATA_1 >= " & Format(Me.Tekst22, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & _
                                  " AND DATA_2 <= " & Format(Me.Tekst24"\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & _
                                  ") AND ([Value3] = " & Chr(34) & Me.Tekst34 & Chr(34) & _
                                  " OR [Value4] = " & Chr(34) & Me.Tekst34.Value & Chr(34) & "))", dbOpenSnapshot)
```

Comment: Value3 and Value4 + there are fields in Query1 (Value1: UCase([I1]), Value2: UCase([I2]) where I1 and I2 are fields in Query1 only. Value1, Value1, I1, I2 - no exist in head table. With this booth codes I have the same error - Too few parameters. Expected 2 etc 3, ... Maybe is  a problem to make rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset from Query1, maybe it should be done from Table.

Comment: Which means Query 1 is expecting parameters. So how about you EDIT your first post with the Query1 included in it?

Comment: I add more info about what I expected from code. Now I have working Query1 with parameters from FORM and I need to print it to Textfile. If I made changes like in add info I still have the same error  Too few parameters. Expected 3. If I run Query1 it shows all values. The problem is in this section Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Query1"). Maybe is other way to take effect.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, you cannot invoke a Query that requires parameters in a RunTime code. You need to create the Query and its parameters in Runtime too. Again **SHOW THE SQL OF QUERY1**.